# Integrating exponentials & delta function

Tags: calculus

I need to integrate

$$\frac{A}{2a\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ik(x+x')}}{(b^2+k^2)}dk$$

I have tried substitution and integration by parts and that hasn't worked. I can see that part of it is the delta function, but I don't really know how to use that fact! I think the delta function is

$$\delta(x+x') = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ik(x+x')}dk$$

Which is almost exactly what I have. If it helps, this is from trying to reverse Fourier transform a function. How can I integrate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\mathcal{F}\left\{\mathrm{e}^{-b|x|}\right\}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \cdot \frac{b}{b^2 + k^2}$ where $\mathcal{F}\left\{f(x)\right\}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-i k x}\, dx$ and  $\mathcal{F}\left\{f(x +x')\right\}=e^{ikx'}\mathcal{F}\left\{f(x)\right\}$

So 
$$\frac{A}{2a\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ik(x+x')}}{b^2+k^2}dk
=\frac{A}{2ab}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{b}{b^2+k^2}e^{ik(x+x')}dk
=\frac{A}{2ab}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{\mathcal{F}\left\{\mathrm{e}^{-b|x+x'|}\right\}\right\}
=\frac{A}{2ab}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \mathrm{e}^{-b|x+x'|}$$

Comment: That is absolute genius! Thank you so much, that's a brilliant solution!